# Activeadmin ajaxing form with geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I have a model relation of:
event -> has many schedules
schedule -> has one address

I wanted to have a extra textfield in the address form which allows user to enter an address and click 'search button', so that user can ajax select the geocoder addresses.

however, I can't seem to create an custom(non model related) textfield or button

```
form do |f|
f.inputs do
  f.input :title
  f.input :category
  f.input :avatar, :as => :file
  f.input :description, as: :html_editor

  #schedules
  f.has_many :schedules do |schedule|
    schedule.inputs "Schedules" do

      link_to("Auto Fill Address", find_location_path)
      #address
      schedule.inputs "Address", :for => [:address, schedule.object.address || Address.new] do |address|
        address.input :full_address
        address.input :city
        address.input :country, :include_blank => true
        address.input :postcode
        address.input :latitude
        address.input :longitude
      end

      #schedule times
      schedule.input :start_time, :as => :just_datetime_picker 
      schedule.input :end_time, :as => :just_datetime_picker
    end
  end
end
f.buttons
```

end

Comment: you can create a custom input http://stackoverflow.com/a/12466213/832759 or may be `address.action, :submit, :as => :button` would work?

Comment: I actually end up with address.actions do with a link_to inside, and that worked :). cheers for the hint !